# How do I edit a photo of myself to not look like me anymore?

Tags: photo-editing

I would like to know how and what specifically to edit in a headshot of myself so that it bears my likeness, but no one could say with certainty anymore that the photo is in fact me.

I've seen this done in real life with makeup, I'm sure most have - at least in the movies, and it's very successful.  It seems like even small changes in proportions and sizes of the facial features can make someone unrecognizable.

I'm wondering what would be the most successful way to do this in a digital photo.  What facial features should I alter?  I'm looking for specifics about spacing between features and changes relative to other features in order that I can keep the same subjective qualities like handsomeness or attractiveness, but make the subject unrecognizable to friends/family.

Comment: This seems a bit off topic as it is a tutorial request and very vague. Do you want to know how to make your nose bigger, eyes smaller, raise your cheek bones, detach earlobes, all of the above?

Comment: @SailorCire I know I can just make the nose bigger or something like that but I think that is too blunt.  Can you provide specifics? Proportion changes? Keeping in mind I still want it to look _like_ me.

Comment: How can you know for sure that you've crossed the threshold of certainty.

Comment: @mattdm a family member or significant other can't say that's it's you with certainty

Comment: IMO asking what facial features to change, and by how much, is really not a photography question, not to mention very subjective, so off-topic.  But if you knew you wanted to change a feature, say widen the distance between the eyes, and want to ask about how to achieve that in photoshop, that would probably be on topic.  Interesting topic and question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceived handsomeness is tightly tied to proportions, so I doubt you could alter one while keeping the other intact. A simple horizontal flip will probably still keep you too recognizable, and [exchanging chin with top of head](http://www.schmidtkord.de/projekte/head-on-top/) might distort more than you'd like.

[Replacing one side of face with flipped version of other side](http://echoism.org/) seems to match the criteria. For better results, no light should be detectable on the photo as coming clearly from a side.